# Is there an audio feature for Gpredict?

Tags: satellites, software, antenna-rotator, gpredict

I am trying to learn about how to talk to satellites and the ARISS via ham radio. What I am wondering is if there is an audio feature I can access for the azimuth. In the sun, I cannot really see the images on the laptop that well, so this would be helpful. I use Gpredict for a satellite tracking program. Any suggestions are always helpful, thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I just wrote you one.**

One of the things Gpredict can do is control antenna rotators (via the *hamlib* driver library). In this case, you're the rotator, but hamlib can't handle that (as far as I know), so instead we'll use a program that pretends to be hamlib (more precisely, pretends to be `rotctld`).

**Setup instructions** (I'm going to assume you're on a unixy system and somewhat comfortable with it; if not I recommend finding someone to help you in person):

1. Install [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), a Python library I used. It should be available through your favorite package manager as well as from their site.
2. Install some text-to-speech software if you don't have any already.
3. Change the line `COMMAND = 'say'` in my program to refer to whatever command your text-to-speech software uses (I hear `espeak` and `spd-say` are some other names; `say` is the command on Mac OS X).
4. In Gpredict, go to Edit → Preferences → Interface → Rotators → Add New. Put in some name or other and leave the rest of the settings alone.

**Usage instructions:**

1. Start my program.
2. In the "module options" menu accessed by the little button in the upper-right corner of the main window, select Antenna Control. In the Antenna Control window:
3. Set the Cycle and Tolerance values to control how often it speaks.
4. Click the Engage button.
5. Choose your target and click the Track button.

**The program:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

COMMAND = 'say'

class RotctlEmulator(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.az = 0.0
        self.el = 0.0
        self.__line_receiver = LineReceiver()
        self.__line_receiver.delimiter = '\n'
        self.__line_receiver.lineReceived = self.__lineReceived

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.__line_receiver.dataReceived(data)

    def __lineReceived(self, line):
        if line == 'p':
            self.transport.write('%.6f\n%.6f\n' % (self.az, self.el))
        elif line.startswith('P'):
            _p, azstr, elstr = line.split()
            new_az = float(azstr)
            new_el = float(elstr)
            self.transport.write('RPRT 0\n')
            self.update(new_az, new_el)
        else:
            print 'unrecognized:', line

    def update(self, new_az, new_el):
        # round to degrees
        new_az = int(round(new_az))
        new_el = int(round(new_el))

        if self.az != new_az or self.el != new_el:
            os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, COMMAND, COMMAND, '%s %s' % (new_az, new_el))
        self.az = new_az
        self.el = new_el

class Factory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return RotctlEmulator()

endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, 'tcp:4533:localhost').listen(Factory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Wow Kevin, I would have said 'try putting shades around the computer screen so you can see it better'.  Your approach is a lot more thorough ;)